# String is not a function error on single Heroku environment

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, web-deployment

I have a problem, specifically when doing an Algolia search using their Node middleware, that gives the error `[TypeError: string is not a function]`

I have 3 identical environments and re-creating the master branch of all those on my local machine does not reproduce the error. The other environments don't have the error.

I've have tried removing and reinstalling npm middleware to see if I forgot to `--save` somehthing and comparing the environmental variables. How else can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: You can find out exactly which line of code causes the error and examine the context around it to see if you can figure out what bad arguments to some function are causing this error.  And, you can set a breakpoint on the offending line and examine the call stack to see how the bad value got where it is.

Comment: @jfriend00 How can I see exactly which line is the problem? Currently, I think I'm just doing `console.log` in this case.

Comment: The error message itself usually indicates line number and filename.

Comment: It only says `2015-05-21T23:15:57.743467+00:00 app[web.1]: [TypeError: string is not a function]` following lines from the heroku router

Comment: Not much we can do here without seeing the environment and code and being able to troubleshoot.  You will have to figure out exactly what code the error is coming from somehow.  Without knowing anything about your project, it's hard for anyone here to advise what steps to take next.

Comment: Should  I make a new ticket for the error messages not showing which line is affected?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  That's probably the library doing it's own catching of the exception and logging a little bit differently.   Unlikely you can change that without knowing where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure the exact cause of this, but switching from Algolia search JS version 1.0 to 3.0 seems to have fixed it. Algolia made a new module, so I had to change from the NPM package `algolia-search` to `algoliasearch`.

I speculate it had something to do with SSL, since the 3rd environment (where it wasn't working) was the only one with SSL (HTTPS). Other than that, I can't think of why it worked everywhere but there, regardless of version. Anyway, there is new syntax in version 3.0 which is also a lot better. Thanks to the Algolia people on GitHub who answered this.